# Linux: Allow only 2 users (out of 3) to access specific folders

Tags: linux

I currently have 3 users in a linux maching: user1, user2, root
The folder /root/test can currently be accessed by user root only.
Is it possible that this folder can be accessed by user1 also, but not user2 ?

user1 belongs to group user1.
user2 belongs to group user2.

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Create another group, add `user1` to it, and give that group the desired permission.  But in this simple case, you could just do `chown user1 /root/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change ownership of that folder to user1 by:

```
chown user1 /root/test
```

It could be also resolved by more complex solution like ACL which allows you to manage file permissions more flexible

```
setfacl -m u:user1:rwx /root/test
```